# Why Garbage Collect in web apps?

Tags: memory-management, go, garbage-collection, erlang, green-threads

Consider building a web app on a platform where every request is handled by a User Level Thread(ULT) (green thread/erlang process/goroutine/... any light weight thread). Assuming every request is stateless and resources like DB connection are obtained at startup of the app and shared between these threads. What is the need for garbage collection in these threads?

Generally such a thread is short running(a few milliseconds) and if well designed doesn't use more than a few (KB or MB) of memory. If garbage collection of the resources allocated in the thread is done at the exit of the thread and independent of the other threads, then there would be no GC pauses for even the 98th or 99th percentile of requests. All requests would be answered in predictable time.

What is the problem with such a model and why is it not being widely used?

Comment: Maybe because the assumptions are not fulfilled in real world applications?

Comment: erlang has GC per erlang process (green thread) so if each request is handled on one process which is not reused you could tweak the GC settings (per process) so you are unlikely to GC except when the process is using a very large amount of memory.  First settings to look at would be min_heap_size and full_sweep_after.  Saying that any erlang GC is not a stop the world so would only affect the latency of the request on that process.

Comment: I know this can be done in erlang, but I wanted to know why doing this is not popular and were there any negatives to doing this.

Answer (score 4):

You assumption might not be true.

> if well designed doesn't use more than a few (KB or MB) of memory

Imagine a function for counting words in a text file which is used in a web app. Some naive implementation could be,

```
def count_words(text):
    words = text.split()
    count = {}
    for w in words:
        if w in count:
            count[w] += 1
        else:
            count[w] = 1
    return count
```

It allocates larger memory than text.

Comment: Most user facing web apps generally receive request, retrieve from db or write to db, return response and the request is done. The assumption is valid for such an app and the model I suggested above would only benefit a latency sensitive application. I can't imagine an application which performs heavy processing per request being latency sensitive, so would not benefit from this model.

Comment: @SacheendraTalluri that's true. however, having a naive mark and sweep gc won't hurt at all. if the max heap size is larger than the work load size, gc won't kick in. otherwise, if gc is not provided, the program has to halt.